# Android RadioGroup single choice doesn't work

Tags: android, radio-group

While adding `RadioButton` programmatically to my `RadioGroup` and then check the buttons, all buttons stay checked, single choice doesn't work, but when I add `RadioButtons` from `XML` it works properly, how to solve this problem?
Here is my code:

```
final RadioGroup pencilContainer = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.pencil_container);

for (int i = 0; i < tubeColors.length; i++) {
    int color = tubeColors[i];
    final RadioButton tube = (RadioButton) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.pencil, pencilContainer, false);
    //RadioButton tube = new RadioButton(this);
    //tube.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.pencil_mask);
    tube.setId(color);
    pencilContainer.addView(tube);
}

pencilContainer.invalidate();
```

Comment: You may have to call [`addView(View child, int index, ViewGroup.LayoutParams params)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html#addView%28android.view.View,%20int,%20android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams%29). Looking at the [implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.0.2_r1/android/widget/RadioGroup.java#RadioGroup.addView%28android.view.View%2Cint%2Candroid.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams%29), it takes care of the checked state. All other `addView(...)` methods don't do any extra work.

Comment: I have impoved indents of your code and highlighted keywords so your question looks more attractive.